# Button size appear different on different devices in Android

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working on android studio and creating a calculator ans I use dp or sp for sizes of buttons. The problem is that, the button size is different on different devices. Please suggest me something

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-s4K8Ru6KGsSGNnWERzNjFrQjA/view?usp=drivesdk) is how it appears on a Samsung Galaxy S5

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-s4K8Ru6KGsNWpqQ2wyZU1xZWc/view?usp=drivesdk) is how it appears on a Galaxy Note Tab

Also I want to disable rotation of the app to only be appeared in portrait view. It should not shift to landscape view.

Comment: In regard to your last question, did you search it via your favorite search engine? A quick search revealed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611457/android-temporarily-disable-orientation-changes-in-an-activity) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021803/disable-and-enable-orientation-changes-in-an-activity-in-android-programatically) even on stackoverflow. Please do research before asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: there is no error in the code
The problem is the size of buttons
Their size is same on all devices
i.e. if I install it on a phone with smaller display, the doesn't fit in and if the phone has a large display major area of the screen is left un-used
and the app fits in the display perfectly if display is around 5" as shown in the pictures